# Find the divergence of the following vector fields

Tags: vector-analysis

> Consider an arbitrary vector field $F$
>
> $$\eqalign{F&=F_1\hat{i}+F_2\hat{j}+F_3\hat{k}\\
> &=F_{C_1}\hat{e}_\rho+F_{C_2}\hat{e}_{\phi}+F_{C_3}\hat{e}_{z}\\
> &=F_{S_1}\hat{e}_r+F_{S_2}\hat{e}_{\theta}+F_{S_3}\hat{e}_{\phi}}$$
>
> So the divergence of $F$ in cartesian,cylindical and spherical
>   coordinates is:
>
> $$\nabla \cdot F=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial
>  F_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial \left(\rho F_{ C_1}\right)}{\partial
>  \rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial F_{C_2}}{\partial
>  \phi}+\frac{\partial F_{C_3}}{\partial z}$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial\left( r^2 F_{ S_1}\right)}{\partial
>  r}+\frac{1}{r \\sin {\theta}}\frac{\partial \left( \\sin {\theta}
>  F_{S_2}\right)}{\partial \theta}+\frac{1}{r
>  \\sin {\theta}}\frac{\partial F_{S_3}}{\partial \phi}$$
>
> U\sin g the appropiate form find the divergence of the following vector
>   fields. Indicate whether the  vector field is compressible or not.
>
> (i)
>   $F(x,y,z)=(x^2+y\\sin {z})\hat{i}+(z^3+e^{3\\cos {z}-y}-y)\hat{j}+z(1-2x)\hat{k}$
>
> (ii)$F(\rho,\phi,z)=\\cos {\left(\rho \phi\right)}\hat{e}_\rho+\\sin {\left(z \phi\right)}\hat{e}_\phi+e^z \hat{e}_z$
>
> (iii)$F(r,\theta,\phi)=\\sin {\left(2\theta\right)}\hat{e}_r+\cot{\left(\theta\right)}\hat{e}_\theta+r^2\hat{e}_\phi$
>
> (iv) Take $F$ to be an arbitrary position vector. Find the divergence
>   in each of coordinate system.

Question ii

Vector field  $$ F(ρ,φ,z)=\cos (ρ φ) eˆ ρ + \sin (z φ) eˆ φ + ez e$$
The divergence is given by:

$$ \nabla \cdot F(ρ,φ,z)=\left(\frac{1}{ρ}\frac{\partial}{\partial ρ}(ρF_C1),\frac{1}{ρ}\frac{\partial F_C2}{\partial φ},\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{ρ}\frac{\partial}{\partial ρ}(ρF_C1)=-\frac{1}{ρ} \sin  ρ$$
$$\frac{1}{ρ}\frac{\partial F_C2}{\partial φ}=\frac{1}{ρ}\cos  φ$$
$$\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z} =e^z $$

---

Qn1 c.

Vector field  $$ F(r,θ,φ)=\sin (2θ) eˆ r+ cot(θ) e
ˆ θ + r^2 e
ˆφ$$
The divergence is given by:

$$ \nabla \cdot F(r,θ,φ)=\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 F_S1),\frac{1}{r \sin (θ)}\frac{\partial }{\partial θ}(\sin (θ) F_S2),\frac{1}{r \sin (θ)} \frac{\partial F_S3}{\partial φ}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 F_S1)=0$$
$$\frac{1}{r \sin (θ)}\frac{\partial }{\partial θ}(\sin (θ) F_S2)=-\frac{1}{r \sin (θ)}csc^2 θ$$
$$\frac{1}{r \sin (θ)} \frac{\partial F_S3}{\partial φ}=0 $$
So the divergence is:
$$ \nabla \cdot F(r,θ,φ)=-\frac{1}{r \sin (θ)}csc^2 θ$$

Qn1 iv)

Given an arbitrary vector  $$ F(u,v,w)$$

a)The divergence in cartesian is given by:

$$ \nabla \cdot F(u,v,w)=\left(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u},\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v},\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial w}\right)$$

b) The divergence in cylindrical is given by:

$$ \nabla \cdot F(u,v,w)=\left(\frac{1}{ρ}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(ρF_C1),\frac{1}{u}\frac{\partial F_C2}{\partial v},\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial w}\right)$$

c) The divergence in cylindrical is given by:

$$ \nabla \cdot F(u,v,w)=\left(\frac{1}{u^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u^2 F_S1),\frac{1}{u \sin (v)}\frac{\partial }{\partial v}(\sin (v) F_S2),\frac{1}{u \sin (v)} \frac{\partial F_S3}{\partial w}\right)$$

Comment: Welcome to mathSE! First look in which coordinates are writed the force fields. Then apply the formula they give you

Comment: Hi, thanks. Which formular?

Comment: The formula of the divegence in cartesian (first), cilindrical (second) and spherical (third one)

Comment: Hi, can you please show the first one, then I will take from there?

Comment: Hi I'm back still need help?

Comment: Yes, on the last part please. Also check how I solved the others

Comment: Please check your divergence definition in the image is the sum of the partial derivatives.

Comment: Am I wrong in my solution?

Comment: Yes see the image or my first example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a vector field of the form $$ F(x,y,z)=(F_1(x,y,z),F_2(x,y,z),F_3(x,y,z))$$
The divergence is given by:

$$ \nabla \cdot F(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}$$
Then for the first case:
$$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}=2x$$
$$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}=-1$$
$$\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}=1-2x$$
So the divergence is:
$$ \nabla \cdot F(x,y,z)=(2x) + (-1) + (1-2x)=0$$

How the divergence is $0$ the field is not compressible.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot. Any idea on what "arbitrary position vector" means? is it the co-od (0,0)? The last bit, No. iv)

Comment: Suppose $F(u,v,w)$ then how you could calculate the divergence?

Comment: what is F(u,v,w)? Give me an example of an arbitrary position vector?